# Darg the screen in android device with MonkeyRunner?

Tags: drag, monkeyrunner

I use python code as follow to horizontal drag the screen, but the device will response with long press event. I do not know why it is.I sincerely somebody could help me to solve this problem, thanks~!

Python code:
device.drag((380,520),(300,520),0.1,10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue with you in my application. My solution is just to disable the long press. Actually, what I found is not only for the 'drag', the onLongPress() would also be triggered by MoneyDevice.press(), then it fails to simulator the double-click by two calls to press().

After all, by disable Long-Press, the drag() and two press() work for me!

Comment: I am rookie and i do know how to disable Long-Press. but still thank you very much for your help. thank you again.